# Windows Snap feature for undecorated windows?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Does anyone know of a way to allow undecorated windows to make use of this feature? The only other alternative would be to implement it all over again. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- dockable could be onĺy [JToolBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)

or

- [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

inside translucent and un_decorated JFrame in Win7

Comment: Do you mean for the implementation of it or for allowing it to behave like a decorated `JFrame`?